# How to solve: Unable to find node on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, scheduler

I am facing this this error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component in my code.

This is my set of code:

```
class CalendarScheduler extends Component {
state = {
    viewModel: schedulerData,
    showBookingDialog: false
}

handleClickOpen = () => {
    // this.setState({ showBookingDialog: true });
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { showBookingDialog: !prevState.showBookingDialog };
    })
};

handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ showBookingDialog: false });
};

render() {
    const { viewModel } = this.state;

    let schedulerData = this.state.viewModel;
    schedulerData.setResources(this.props.rooms);

    return (
        <div>
            <Scheduler schedulerData={viewModel}
                prevClick={this.prevClick}
                nextClick={this.nextClick}
                onSelectDate={this.onSelectDate}
                newEvent={this.newEvent}
            />
            {this.state.showBookingDialog === true && (
                <BookingDialog 
                    open={this.state.showBookingDialog} 
                    onClose={this.handleClose} />
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is my function:

```
    newEvent = (schedulerData, slotId, slotName, start, end, type, item) => {
    this.setState({
        showBookingDialog: true
    });
```

My error message is pointing to this.setState inside newEvent.

Comment: In order for anyone to help, you'll need to show more of the code around this and what the exact error is.

Comment: i have edit my question, appreciate the help. thank you!! :)

Comment: How does the “newEvent” function get called?